# Leopard won't remember default programs

Tags: macos, applications, mail.app, leopard, web-browsing

Everytime I restart/boot my mac and open up a mail application (thunderbird) or a web browser (firefox or chrome) I am always asked if I want to make it the default. This happens even if I click yes.

So, for some reason osx isn't remembering what I set as the default mail or web browser. I have already repaired disk permissions which didn't fix the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: The permissions was a very long shot for this issue - but do reboot into safe mode (or run a repair of the filesystem using fsck/Disk Utility) and report back. Another thing to try is to make a new user account and see if things stick there better. I'd guess a corrupt preference file is hosed, but you might have to be systematic about troubleshooting this to find the glitch on your mac ...

Comment: Definitely try that!

Comment: Are you using FileVault, by chance?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was using the root user. Creating a new user sorted everything out!

Answer (score 0):

Tyr setting it within the Safari or Mail preferences as described here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1637

Answer (score 0):

Try to set default apps with [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/)